# How to get the first letter from the current file for a VSCode snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to get the first letter from the current file in order to create a snippet that should look like:

```js
const f = new Object()
```

Where `f` is the first letter of the current file. I know I can access to the file name by using `TM_FILENAME_BASE`, but how can access to the first letter only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"body": ["${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.).*/$1/}"],`

`(.)` capture the first character in group 1
`.*` match the rest, you won't use this later but you do want to match it
`$1` replace the entire match with just the first capture group

In general, you are looking for [snippet variable transforms](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms).